# how to make Wildcards consider spaces between

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm working with a table with three columns( ID | NOTE |TAG)

ID- primary key

NOTE- some things

TAG- contains values separated with space

imagine that 
id-1 contains TAG- *computer javaScript java forton cellphone*

and id-2 contains TAG- *computer java forton c++ android*

When using a Wildcard to search for term *java* which is in middle of a string the SQLITE also shows the row containing *javascript*

My query
`" LIKE '%" + "java" + "%'";` this shows the rows if the word *java* is found anywhere inside (i.e) it shows *java* as well as *javaScript* as well as *Scriptinjava*

how to make it show only *java* ??

Comment: You should store the tags properly in a junction table, with one row per `id` and per `tag`.  Then you won't have such problems using them.

Comment: yes you are right but this is just a small project and I though this table design is enough for a simple project like this :0 but now feeling irritated about the decision

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  Fortunately, most people know that storing lists in strings is a bad idea.  So, they use the proper SQL structure, which is a table with one row per list item.

But, we we are stuck with other people's bad decisions and cannot fix the underlying data structure, it is possible to use SQL to do what you want.  In MySQL, you can express this as:

```
WHERE concat(' ', tags, ' ') LIKE '% '" + "java" + "' %'
```

(I am assuming that the `+` is the string concatenation operator in the application language you are using.)

Comment: Yes you are right the + a concatenation in the language i'm using (java) anyway you syntax giving an error >> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "java": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id,notes,tags FROM mainnotestable WHERE concat(' ', tags, ' ') LIKE '% 'java' %'

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
where tags = 'java'
or tags like 'java %' -- starts with java
or tags like '% java %' -- java in the middle
or tags like '% java' -- ends with java
```